How to create dummy copies of folder or file with a batch file via right click menu item in Explorer?
So, I want to right click on a folder and create the dummy copy of that folder with 0 byte files. I use robocopy command as follows:
For a folder:
Robocopy /Create /Purge /S "%cd%" "%cd% Dummy"
Pause

For a file:
Robocopy /Create /Purge "%cd%" "%cd%/Dummy"
pause

I created the two batch files folders.bat and files.bat with the command lines above, put them into the folder C:\com and added them to the registry to have it in right click menu of any folder and any file.
For folders in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Dummy\command as (Default) value of type REG_SZ:
"C:\com\folders.bat" "%1"

So, now the problem is that the batch file for the folder creates the dummy of the parent folder with all the subfolders and files
and the batch file for files creates the dummies of all the files in the folder into a dummy folder in the same folder.
It works fine if I open a command prompt and run the batch file from the command prompt.
Please check this image with the windows on running the batch files via Explorer context menu on a file and a folder and their registration in registry.

Your batch files appear to be using %cd%, but does not indicate what to use as the current working directory from the outset. You appear to be passing one argument to each batch file, but neither of those are currently using the argument at all. I should also mention, that Robocopy is an independent utility, and as such could be run directly from the context menu without involving cmd.exe or a batch file.

"%1" in the registry is a placeholder for the right clicked file/folder name enclosed in double quotes. Your batch files reference the dynamic variable CD. %CD% expands to full path of the current directory not ending with a backslash, except the current directory is the root directory of a drive. The batch files should reference instead the file/folder name passed by explorer.exe as last argument string to the registered batch file on starting %ComSpec% with option /C and the registered batch file name for processing the appropriate registered batch file.
There can be used a single batch file C:\com\CreateDummy.cmd with following commented code:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Is the batch file called without any argument string
rem or with an empty string as first argument string?
rem Yes, exit the batch file processing as nothing to do.
if "%~1" == "" exit /B
rem Is the batch file called with the name of an existing folder?
if exist "%~1\" goto Folder
rem Is the batch file called with a string NOT referencing an existing file?
if not exist "%~1" exit /B

rem The batch file is called with the name of an existing file.
rem Create a subdirectory with name Dummy in the directory of the existing
rem file and create in subdirectory Dummy a zero byte file for each file in
rem the directory of the existing file and then exit the batch processing.
rem %~dp1 expands to fully directory path of the existing file always ending
rem with a backslash which must be considered here for the correct syntax.
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%~dp1\" "%~dp1Dummy" /Create /Purge /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS
exit /B

:Folder
rem ROBOCOPY interprets a backslash left to a backslash or a double quote
rem character as escape character for the following \ or " which must be
rem considered on processing a folder of which name ends already with a
rem backslash. Get the fully directory path of the passed folder without
rem a backslash at the end.
for %%I in ("%~1\.") do set "SourceFolder=%%~fI" & set "DestinationFolder=%%~fI Dummy"
rem The root directory of a drive ends always with a backslash. There must
rem be appended an additional backslash on drive letter, colon and backslash
rem for source path for ROBOCOPY and the destination directory path is in
rem this special case the subdirectory Dummy in the root directory of the
rem drive instead of the existing directory path with a space and Dummy
rem appended for a parallel created Dummy directory as no directory can
rem be created parallel to the root directory of a drive.
if "%SourceFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "SourceFolder=%SourceFolder%\" & set "DestinationFolder=%SourceFolder%Dummy"
rem The source directory path is now either with no backslash at the end or
rem with two backslashes at the end on being the root directory of a drive.
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SourceFolder%" "%DestinationFolder%" /Create /Purge /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS

The lines beginning with the command rem describe the command lines. The remarks can be removed for faster processing of the batch file.
The batch file works also for most but not all file/folder names passed to the batch file with a relative path. The Windows File Explorer passes right clicked file/folder name always with absolute path to the Windows Command Processor.
The registration should be with the command line:
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /D /C C:\com\CreateDummy.cmd "%1"

That is more efficient on execution instead of registering just the batch file with the placeholder "%1".
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

call /? … explains %1 and %~1 and %~dp1
cmd /? … explains the cmd options /D and /C and how all further argument strings are interpreted by the Windows Command Processor processing the specified batch file with right clicked file/folder name enclosed in " passed by explorer.exe to cmd.exe and further to the batch file.
echo /?
exit /?
for /?
goto /?
if /?
rem /?
robocopy /?
set /?
setlocal /?

Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file explains the unconditional command operator & as used twice in the batch file above.
There should be read also Microsoft documentation about Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces.

Amazing Amazing Amazing man
thanks a lot Mofi you are the man
it works great for folder doesnt create the subfolders copy though plz hep with that as well
and plz help with  creating the dummy file for one single file in the same folder as well if possible (right click click on the file and create dummy of that file if same name is the problem then removing the extension or add some word at the end like "dummy" thanks again
really appreciate it as i was trying to do this for a while now

@GurpreetSidhu Please edit your question and add examples to describe better what should be created on running the batch file on a folder and what should be created on running the batch file on a file. My answer is currently for the code provided by you. If there should be created something else, you have to describe it which is best done with examples.

basically the last code that you generated will only make the dummy copies of the files in that folder. it doesn't create the dummies of sub-folders, second thing if possible is I want to right click on a file and make a dummy copy of that file within the same folder if possible (as it cant be same name add something at the end of the name as 'dummy') let me create some pictures to explain it better

here is the image https://i.postimg.cc/hPFcKdTq/Image3.png     it will only create the dummy of the files in the folder but not of the subfolders

If you would run robocopy /? in a command prompt window as I wrote in my answer and would read the output usage help, you would have get knowledge about the ROBOCOPY options /S and /E and their meanings. Append to the last command line in the batch file /S and see if that is producing the directory tree with the subdirectories and files as wanted by you. For creating a dummy file just for the single right clicked file replace the first ROBOCOPY command line by if not "%~n1" == "" (set /P =0<nul 1>"%~dpn1 Dummy%~x1") else set /P =0<nul 1>"%~f1 Dummy"

Let me know if those two changes produce the expected files and directories. I will edit the answer in this case and change the explaining comments.
